# Conditional Execution of conditions based on return value of CASE statement

Tags: sql

I want to realize this functionality in SQL (basically b=2 and c in (3,4,5) are two conditions that I want to add to my select statement at the top level).

If a=1 then I want the first condition to be checked, else the second condition should be checked.

```
CASE 
  WHEN a=1 THEN {AND b=2}
  ELSE {AND c in (3,4,5)}
```

The total query is too complex for me to separately keep the entire query inside the THEN clause.

Comment: What are your expected results?  You can use multiple `when` statements to simulate `if / else` statements...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM Table
WHERE
SomeCondition
AND
(
     (a=1 AND b=2)
 OR
     ((NOT a=1) AND (c in (3,4,5)))
)
```

Comment: Ah... seeing your answer I got that "Why didn't I think of that" moment :P

Comment: Glad we could help.